# Consecutive duplicate words to change with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str="Foo bar bar end."
var word="bar"
var regex = new RegExp("([\\s]|^|>)("+word+")(<|[\\s]|$)", "gi");
str=str.replace(regex,' <span class="selected">$2</span> ');
```

result:

```
Foo <span class="selected">bar</span> bar end.
```

Why only first `bar` changed?

Comment: The point is that your last capturing group consumes the trailing delimiter. Use a lookahead. Or a word boundary.

Comment: could this string `"Foo bar bar bar end."`  be considered in your case?

Comment: I tried and successful results. Thank you for remember me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of overlapping matches. ie, your last capturing group consumes the trailing delimiter. Inorder to make it not to consume the following character, change the last capturing group to a positive lookahead pattern which won't consume any character but do assertion.

```
var regex = new RegExp("([\\s>]|^)("+word+")(?=[<\\s]|$)", "gi");
str=str.replace(regex,'$1<span class="selected">$2</span>');
```

Comment: @GalipÖzen Welcome to StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer